# css table last row is smaller when using border

Tags: css

When using `border-top` with `border-collapse`, the last row of table becomes smaller in height by `border-width / 2` pixels. For example, with 2px border, the last row is 1px smaller; with 10px border, it is 5px smaller and so on...

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

```js
/* Just for styling. Writes each cell's height in it. */

document.querySelectorAll('td')
  .forEach((cell) => {
    cell.innerHTML = cell.offsetHeight + "px";
  });
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.t1 tr {
    border-top: solid 2px black;
}

.t2 tr {
    border-top: solid 100px black;
}

/* Just for styling */
td {
    padding: 12px 40px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2>2px border</h2>
<table class="t1">
    <tr style="background: cornflowerblue">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background: brown">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background: olive">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h2>100px border</h2>
<table class="t2">
    <tr style="background: cornflowerblue">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background: brown">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background: olive">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Update

The problem shows itself when you want to sort columns.
In a normal, static table, that 1px isn't a huge deal; nobody will notice it. But when you want to change the order of rows (by sorting), there is a "jump".

[image: table sort gif]

Comment: Does not seem to be the case on my browser (currently on Chrome for Android). What's your browser?

Comment: if you use border-collapse in your table, then the borders of each td will overlap the tds around each other

Comment: @Noam I have the problem in both Chrome and Firefox (Developer Edition) on Windows.

Comment: Do you see a difference in the *content height* - the colored area in your example? If so, please post a screenshot. If you mean in the measured height I see what you mean, but it's more like a weirdness in handling a weird definition - table cells with only top border. The point with border-collapse is that even if you define a border only for one cell, it belongs to it's neighbour too.

Comment: No. The colored areas all have the same height.

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example of the sorting code?